# ¿Como establecer la conexión php 5.6 con sql server 2014 en utf-8 sobre IIS 10?

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, iis, odbc

Tengo instalado un proyecto en ***DESARROLLO*** con PHP 5.6 sobre IIS 10 en ***WINDOWS*** y me conecto a una base de datos SQL Server 2014 con un collation **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS**. El problema que estoy teniendo es que al recuperar los datos la Base me regresa caracteres extraños, cuando hay acentos y eñes. *¿Como puedo establecer la conexión para que maneje la codificación en utf-8 o su equivalente (he leído que SQL no maneja utf8)?*

Este es mi código de conexión :

```
$this->datosConexion=@parse_ini_file($rutaProperties, false, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
$this->schema=$this->datosConexion["sqlsvrSchema"];
$this->parametros = "Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;Server=". $this->datosConexion["sqlsvrNombreServidor"]. ";Database=".$this->datosConexion["sqlsvrBaseDatos"];
$this->conexion=odbc_connect($this->parametros,$this->datosConexion["sqlsvrUsuario"],$this->datosConexion["sqlsvrPass"]);
```

Cabe mencionar que tengo esta solución montada en ambiente de ***PRUEBAS*** en un servidor ***LINUX*** ubuntu 13.9, con apache 2.4.7 y PHP 5.5.9 donde apache y php tienen configurado el utf-8 y aqui si funciona correctamente.

El problema solo ocurre al recuperar información de la base de datos desde windows, y lo se porque he debugueado y desde ahi aparecen los caracteres raros.

Tenemos distintos ambientes porque tenemos en puerta varias migraciones y debe funcionar correctamente en ambos lugares con el mismo código.

Esta es la parte del SELECT:

```
$sql = "SELECT id_dependencia ,dependencia_descr ,dependencia_descr_abr FROM egresos.administracion.cat_dependencias WHERE estatus_dep='VI' order by id_dependencia;"
$parametros =array();
$resultado= odbc_prepare( $this->conexion,$sql);
if($resultado != false){
    $result= odbc_execute( $resultado,$parametros);
    if ($result){
        $nowRows=odbc_num_rows ($resultado);
        while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($resultado)) {
            foreach($row as $key => $value) {
                $datos_pr[$key] = $value;
            }
            $datos[] = $datos_pr;
            $datos_pr=null;
        }
        $bandera=true;
        odbc_free_result($resultado);
    }else{
        $bandera= false;
        $nowRows=0;
        $msg = odbc_errormsg($this->conexion);
    }
}else{
    $bandera= false;
    $nowRows=0;
    $msg = odbc_errormsg($this->conexion);
}
```

Espero alguien me pueda apoyar (Uso visual studio con php tools).

Comment: ¿Cual es el tipo que usas en SQL Server para los campos que te regresan valores "extraños"? ¿`varchar`? ¿`nvarchar`?

Comment: el tipo de dato es varchar

Comment: Prueba con `nvarchar`, que es el tipo que sabe manejar Unicode. `varchar` no maneja Unicode.

Comment: y no me afectará en linux??

Comment: No puedo decirte a ciencia cierta sin tener un conocimiento completo de tus datos, configuración, etc. Simplemente te doy una pista: que `varchar` no esta diseñado para manejar Unicode, pero `nvarchar` sí. Tal vez hay otros aspectos que tengas que considerar, pero este es uno de esos.

Comment: Ok, he realizado el alter tabla a nvarchar pero el comportamiento es el mismo: funciona bien en linux y mal en windows. A mi me parece que el problema es en la configuración de la conexión hacia la base de datos pero he probado con `odbc_exec($this->conexion, "SET NAMES UTF8");` y con `"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"` en los parámetros de conexión, no se si alguien pueda ponerlo correctamente, tal vez me equivoque en la sintaxis

Answer (score 0):

algo similar me paso ami también con la versión de mssql2014 lo que hice fue sobre la consulta, específicamente en los campos que te traen los caracteres extraños, fue un cast que va asi:

```
 select CAST(CAST(NOMBRE_ATRIBUTO AS varbinary(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NOMBRE_ATRIBUTO FROM TABLE;
```

después en el código php sobre el campo le hice una conversión a utf8

```
$Response = new Response();
$Response->NOMBRE = utf8_encode($row['NOMBRE_ATRIBUTO']);
```

espero te sea de ayuda.

saludos.

Comment: gracias, lo que busco es no modificar el código, o tal vez solo los atributos de la conexión de tal manera que el código sea portable